# Can the variance of two subsets of an observation of a random variable be greater than variance of the original complete set of observations?

Tags: statistics, variance, covariance

So if I have a finite set $ S \subset \mathbb{R} $ that can be partitioned in any form into two subsets $ S_1, S_2 $ such that $ S = S_1 \cup S_2 $ and $ S_1 \cap S_2 = \emptyset $.

Can I form $ S_1, S_2 $ such that $ Var(S_1) > Var(S) $ and $ Var(S_2) > Var(S) $ where $ Var(X) = E( (X - E(X))^2 ) $?

There are obvious cases if we only care about the variance of one set's variance, but I can't prove it (or find a case true case) for boths sets having greater variance. I every wrote a program to run through 1000000 random cases and did not find any true cases.

### Revised question per discussion below accepted answer:

Per aiden's request, I believe a better formulation of his question is as follows:

If I have a set $S$ of observations of a real-valued random variable,  with variance $\sigma^2_S$, is there a partition of the observations into two disjoint subsets,  $S_1$ and $S_2$, where each subset has a larger variance than the original pooled set: $\sigma^2_{S_1} \geq \sigma^2_{S_2} > \sigma^2_S$?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $\mathrm{Var}(S)$. Variance is defined for random variables, not subsets of $\Bbb R$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am understanding your question to ask if such a partition exists, and not does a set exhibit this behavior for all partitions. We know that:
$$
\begin{align}
Var(aX + bY) &= a^2 Var(X) + b^2 Var(Y) + 2abCov(X, Y)\\
&= a^2 Var(X) + b^2 Var(Y) + 2ab\rho_{X, Y}\sigma_X\sigma_Y
\end{align}
$$
Now $\rho$ can be -1. So if $X$ is negatively correlated with $Y$, we can create cases where  $Var(X \cup Y) \leq \min(Var(X), Var(Y))$

For example, try the following in R:

```
X <- seq(-4, 4)
Y <- -X
Z <- c(X, Y)
var(X); var(Y); var(Z)
```

You get:

```
[1] 7.5
[1] 7.5
[1] 7.058824
```

### Update

If you do not allow multiple entries of the same value, try this:

```
X <- c(-1, 2)
Y <- -X
Z <- c(X, Y)
var(X); var(Y); var(Z)

[1] 4.5
[1] 4.5
[1] 3.333333
```

Comment: Two concerns. First, I think you meant to put Var(X union Y) in the 4th line ( Var(X \cup Y) in Latex). Also, this is clearly true, as you have a clear example. What then is wrong with vadim123's argument below?

Comment: What is meant by $X\cap Y$ (or $X\cup Y$ for that matter)? How do you apply a set operation to a function?

Comment: @Math1000, I am understanding the elements to be observations of one or more random variables. The question, as I understood it, was can there be a partition of the observation such that the variance of the elements of the subsets are both greater than the variance of the pooled observations.

Comment: @aidan.plenert.macdonald I'm not sure, but I do not see where vadim123 took the covariance of the two subsets into account in the second line of the first equation.

Comment: What do you mean by $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are sets? Also, please also give your examples in standard mathematical notation for the benefit of readers who don't know R.

Comment: @Rahul, under the assumption that the sets comprise elements which are observations of a random variable or variables, the covariance of the observations in the disjoint subsets for a particular partitioning. This does treat the elements as observations from two different variables. As for standard mathematical notation, please feel free to update the post if you feel it needs. I think the information is relatively clear, even if the notation is slightly abused, but others may differ.

Comment: I don't see how that makes sense. To define covariance of two random variables you need to know their joint distribution, and I don't know where you're getting that from. For example, say $X=\{0,1,2\}$ and $Y=\{-10,10\}$. What is $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$?

Comment: And sorry, I should have been more clear. *I* don't know R so I don't understand your code. What is `seq`? What is `c`?

Comment: @Rahul, it doesn't make sense in as much as the original question is problematic; what is the variance of a set? So I chose to interpret it in light of what I believe was the intent of the OP; does there exist a set of observations of a random variable which can be partitioned so that the variance of each subset is > than that of the pool? The answer is clearly yes, that is how insurance works. I gave a specific example with same-sized sets that can be explained using covariance. I'd be surprised if there does not exist at least one dissimilar sized partition with similar properties.

Comment: @Rahul, `c` = concatenate. `seq` = sequence.

Comment: I apologize for any confusion in what I am asking, I come from a Computer Science background, as such I often don't know proper naming and notation conventions. Avraham has the right idea behind my question. I am asking about sets of observations of random variables. And I understand vadim123's answer below. He answered a slightly different question that what I was asking. Also, @avraham if you are willing, please correct my question to be mathematically proper. I simply wouldn't know how to do so.

Comment: @aidan.plenert.macdonald I added a revision to the question above; do you concur?

Comment: Looks good. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is assumed that the random variables are defined as equiprobable on the subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ on which they are defined.

$$\frac{1}{|S_1|}\sum_{z\in S_1}(z-\mu(S_1))^2+\frac{1}{|S_2|}\sum_{z\in S_2}(z-\mu(S_2))^2=Var(S_1)+Var(S_2)>\\>Var(S)=\frac{1}{|S|}\sum_{z\in S}(z-\mu(S))^2=\frac{1}{|S|}\sum_{z\in S_1}(z-\mu(S))^2+\frac{1}{|S|}\sum_{z\in S_2}(z-\mu(S))^2$$

We subtract.
$$\left(\frac{1}{|S_1|}-\frac{1}{|S|}\right)\sum_{z\in S_1}(z-\mu(S_1))^2-(z-\mu(S))^2+\\+\left(\frac{1}{|S_2|}-\frac{1}{|S|}\right)\sum_{z\in S_2}(z-\mu(S_2))^2-(z-\mu(S))^2>0$$

Now, each sum is nonpositive, and each leading coefficient is positive.  Hence together the left hand side is nonpositive, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you. I am a bit concerned about claiming that each summation is non-positive. I believe I understand the intuition that the expected value of S will be farther from all z's that the expected value of S_1. But I wasn't sure if this was a valid argument.